# Converting long string to individual words in Red/Rebol

Tags: string, list, rebol, red

How can a string with a sentence be converted to a series of words, e.g. convert following string to:

```
str: "This is a sentence with some words"
```

to a series of:

```
["This" "is" "a" "sentence" "with" "some" "words"]
```

There seems to be a split function in [Rebol3](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/split.html) but no such function in [Rebol2](http://www.rebol.com/docs/dictionary.html3).

I tried following code with parse but it does not work:

```
str: "This is a sentence with some words"
strlist: []
parse str [
    some got: " " (append strlist got) ]
```

Error is:

```
** Script Error: Invalid argument: got
```

How can this be achieved (a method with parse will be preferable)?

Comment: In Rebol 2, you split using PARSE: `parse "foo bar baz" " "`

Comment: How does it work?

Comment: convenience feature, not recommended or available in rebol3 or red

Comment: Yep, just noted for historical reasons. Use SPLIT instead.

Comment: See [documentation](http://www.rebol.com/docs/core23/rebolcore-15.html#section-2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rebol 2, this would be:

```
str: "This is a sentence with some words"
parse str none
```

resulting in:

```
["This" "is" "a" "sentence" "with" "some" "words"]
```

As mentioned in the comments on your post, [the documentation](http://www.rebol.com/docs/core23/rebolcore-15.html#section-2).   Parse has two modes, one of which is string splitting.

Rebol 3, `split` will work.

Comment: You can also add how it can be done in Red language.

Answer (score 2):

It will be

```
split str " "
```

Where split is function. First argument is your string, and second — delimiter.

Comment: This does not work in Rebol 2.7.8. `** Script Error: split has no value`

Comment: Can't find documentation for Rebol 2. In Rebol 3 should work: http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/split.html